# Let $\exists N\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x>N:A(x)$ for a statement $A(x)$. Do I need to define $x$ to be in $\mathbb{R}$ or is this already given by $x>N$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

> Let $\exists N \in\mathbb{R}:\forall x>N:A(x)$ for some statement
> $A(x)$. Do I need to define $x$ to be in $\mathbb{R}$ or is this
> already given by the fact that $x>N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your formal language defines bounded quantifiers. If we are careful, we only use unbounded quantifiers $\forall x$ and $\exists x$ and spell out restrictions further down. And all bounded quantifiers can (and should) be defined in terms of these workarounds (and always with the intention of more legible and less convoluted sentences).

If we work in set theory, bounded quantifiers a la $\forall x\in y\colon\phi\equiv\forall x\colon x\in y\to \phi$ and $\exists x\in y\colon \phi\equiv \exists x\colon (x\in y\land \phi)$ suggest themselves.

If your domain of discourse allows so, other similar constructs may come in handy - and can be used once they are defined accordingly. Given suitable definitions, we For example, it *may* be useful to have bounded quantifiers involving the order relation and then you may want to *define* these accordingly; it seems most useful to define $\forall x>y$ to mean "for all *real* numbers $x$ that are greater than the (real) number $y$".

In other (number thoretical) context, we may want introduce bounded quantifiers in terms of divisibility and for example write
$$ \forall n>1\colon (n\,\text{prime}\lor \exists d\mid n\colon (1<d\land d^2<n))$$
with the interpretation "every *natural* number greater than $1$ is prime or has a proper divisor $\le \sqrt n$".

Comment: Your answer is much better and complete than mine (+1).

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful explanation. I always thought that the meanings of the individual bounded quantifiers were fixed. Now I know that different definitions can be made for appropriate areas if they increase readability and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The condition $ x>N $ does not define precisely the variabe or the parameter $ x$.

It doesn't say if $ x $ is in $\Bbb N $ or $ \Bbb Q $ or elsewhere.

If $ x $ is a real,
Your proposition should be written as

$$(\exists N\in \Bbb R)\;:\;(\forall x\in \Bbb R)$$
$$\Bigl(x>N \implies P(x)\Bigr)$$

Or in an equivalent way
$$(\exists N\in \Bbb R)\;: $$
$$\Bigl((\forall x\in \Bbb R \;:\; x>N)\; \; P(x)\Bigr)$$

Comment: I think you meant to write $\exists N \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @lemontree Yes in fact. Thanks for this.

Comment: Thank you. Why shouldn't I write $\exists N\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x \in\mathbb{R}:x>N:A(x)$?

Comment: The vertical two points $:$ mean such that. You don't need the last one.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!